# Unable to post on FB fanpage using SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Exception occured, code: 200 with message: (#200) Permissions error I am able to post on users wall but not able to post on fanpage

Comment: that´s definitely not enough information to help you in a serious way. take your time to come up with a sophisticated and detailed description of your problem, including what exactly you have tried so far - step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Check this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Then scroll down to where it talks about **Permissions That Require Review**

> Permissions That Require Review
>
> Permissions that require review are generally reviewed within 3 business days. Some permissions may take up to 7 days to review, and are marked as such in the reference.
>
> Extended profile properties. These permissions are all sensitive properties that may or may not be part of a person's public profile.
>
> Extended permissions. These include the most sensitive pieces of profile information. One of the these permissions is publishing stories to a person's Facebook profile. All extended permissions appear on a separate screen during the login flow so a person can decide if they want to grant them.
>
> Open Graph permissions. These permissions are for gaining access to any open graph data stored in someone's profile.
>
> Page permission. This permission allows you to administer any Facebook Pages that the person manages.

I think that would fall under `Page permission' since a fan page is a page and not a user's wall.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved..

I was using the user access token instead of page access token for posting on fanpage.

From here I generated the pageaccess token:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

Comment: Then please use Stack Exchange properly and accept my answer since it was correct.